# Jenkins configuration with jira.Auto defect reporting on jira if build failed

Tags: jenkins, jira

Hello i am new to jenkins sorry if i can't explain my problem pretty much clear.
I am assigned a task to auto report defect to jira from jenkins against failed cases.
I have installed following plugin

1)Jira Plugin
2)JiraTestResultReporter plugin

i have successfully implemented the configurations required on Configure screen.
After executing the build i am facing the following  issue.

```
    RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(400), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=400, errors={summary=Summary must be less than 255 characters.}, errorMessages=[]}]}
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.DelegatingPromise.claim(DelegatingPromise.java:47)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.JiraTestResultReporter.JiraUtils.createIssueInput(JiraUtils.java:114)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.JiraTestResultReporter.JiraTestDataPublisher.raiseIssues(JiraTestDataPublisher.java:248)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.JiraTestResultReporter.JiraTestDataPublisher.contributeTestData(JiraTestDataPublisher.java:187)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.parseAndAttach(JUnitResultArchiver.java:200)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.perform(JUnitResultArchiver.java:154)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1835)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(400), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=400, errors={summary=Summary must be less than 255 characters.}, errorMessages=[]}]}
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$2.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:176)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$2.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:170)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.ResponsePromiseMapFunction.apply(ResponsePromiseMapFunction.java:67)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.ResponsePromiseMapFunction.apply(ResponsePromiseMapFunction.java:11)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$3.apply(Promises.java:268)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$2.onSuccess(Promises.java:158)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:975)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:253)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList$RunnableExecutorPair.execute(ExecutionList.java:149)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:134)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:170)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$3.apply(Promises.java:268)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$2.onSuccess(Promises.java:158)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:975)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:253)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList$RunnableExecutorPair.execute(ExecutionList.java:149)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:134)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:170)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$1$1.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:46)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable$1.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:197)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.runInContext(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:90)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:192)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help with your specific error, but maybe someone else. Please add all information what you did and what changed to the question. You have to make it clear and easy for everyone to understand your problem. You can also remove unnecessary comments. I will do so with mine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem what I also fessing was `${DEFAULT_SUMMARY}`,which was more than

> 255

characters in title of JIRA create defect and that is why this issue was occurring.

I think you have to change the parameter of default summary to test name as follows so you won't this issue any more.

Before- `${DEFAULT_SUMMARY}`

After- `${TEST_NAME}`

Let me know if that works for you.

[image: Jenkins-JiraChange]

Comment: Did you attach the screenshot with defect in case of failure

Comment: @Afshan Screenshot you cannot send with this plugin. You have to use another plugin. Also as per your question, screenshots you didnt mention. Also this jira plugin is used to update/create jira through jenkins.

Comment: Can you please share your experinece for that plugin if used.I already asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55015955/attach-screenshot-to-failed-case-on-jira-through-jenkins